# Read Json from request in Spark

Tags: javascript, json, request, spark-java

I'm strating with Spark, and I'm trying to get a request with a Json as parameter.
This is how I send it:

```
  let data = {
    req: this.state.results
  }

  const apiAddress = 'http://localhost:4567/results';
  fetch(apiAddress, {
    method: 'post',
    body: data
  }).then( (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res
  });
```

And I'm getting this on the server side calling `request.body()`:

```
Request ------WebKitFormBoundaryBvud3Cn7ZmzAtAXt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryBvud3Cn7ZmzAtAXt--
```

But I cant find a way to know what's in that Object or how to get to its parameters.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with [tag:java].  I have removed this tag for you.

Comment: If you need a JSON, then you need to convert the object to JSON format first. `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Great! So I guess now I have to map it to a Class to access the arguments, right?